# How to stop stops unauthorized persons from initiating a deployment of a user story to production

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I would like to have some advise on the issues we have in our copado Environment

The issue we have is , There is nothing that stops unauthorized persons from initiating a deployment of a user story to production.

We have encountered this issue several times when other Team accidentally pushed something to Production Environment that caused a business disruption.

I would like to come up with some ideas on how we can prevent this, while still allowing our teams to promote code through the lower sandbox environments.

Hoping to get some Advise from the Experts.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.